# Adding an 'You tagged this as SQL maybe you should also tag as specific DBMS' hint when posting questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions

The problem:

Quite often questions tagged as SQL are missing tags for the specific DBMS used and would benefit from it.

This leads to the first comment being something along

> What is your RDBMS: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc. ?

and then a wait until the OP clarifies.

I think adding an UI hint when posting a question would increase the likelihood of getting it right from the start. If the system would suggest that additional product specific tags be added too when only tagging as SQL. Maybe this hint would be limited to just users below a reputation threshold, or limited to the first N questions, after which one would assume that the point has been received.

Rationale:

1. To improve quality of questions
2. To remove the speed bump that comes from having to wait for clarification.
3. Questions would get attention from the "right" people (interested in a specific DBMS for instance).
4. Answers would be tailored for the specific instead of the general (if that is what is desired - of course sometimes it isn't).

Thoughts?

Comment: What other tags would this support? Are there other tags that might benefit from the same idea, as "You're asking a question about gcc. What specific version are you using?" or "You're using C# and asking about something related to the user interface. Is this WPF or WinForms? What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?". Or "You're asking about C++. To which version of the standard should answers refer?"  IOW, where would this feature stop? It's clearly not limited to SQL.

Comment: @KenWhite Good point, I just thought of sql as that is what I look at most and I don't know if other tags might have similar issues. I imagine more tags could benefit from this much like your examples.

Comment: :-) I think you missed my point. How would you implement this for more than the SQL tag? (You clearly can't hardcode "If the question is about SQL, and if it doesn't include a tag that is in this list of DBMSs, nag them to add a tag".) How would you decide which tags needed the additional information, and what specific additional information should be suggested?

Comment: @KenWhite Guess I did miss that part :) I have no idea if it's practical or impossible, but the people who built SO seem smart and I'm sure they could manage this :) maybe tag hierarchies or families could work, or just hard code it for sql and I'd be happy :D

Comment: "Hard-code it for SQL" would never work - see the part about "this list of DBMSs". Which specific DBMSs should be in that list? What happens when new DBMSs come out next week, month, or year? How do we decide that they're popular enough to add to the list (or have lost enough popularity to be removed)?

Comment: Similar request related to python: [Force the OP to add their python version as a tag, along with the python tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198195/force-the-op-to-add-their-python-version-as-a-tag-along-with-the-python-tag)... many of the arguments I made are similar here, although there is a difference between "force" and "suggest"

Comment: @KenWhite I didn't mean for the hint to suggest any specific DBMS but rather hint that maybe the user should consider adding a specific of his choice. The db names would just serve as a pointer to the fact that specific tags do exist. I would use "mysql, PostgreSQL, oracle and MSSQL" as examples as those seem to have the highest name recognition (my impression, I could be wrong about that).

Comment: Similar things have been asked for before [see Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178367/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips) on MSE.

Comment: @bluefeet: Thanks for finding that - I knew I'd seen it before, but couldn't locate it searching. And it's even about SQL, which seems kind of humorous. :-)

Comment: @bluefeet That's pretty much exactly what I would like to see. Even has Clippy :) would vote to close my request as duplicate if only I could find how...

Comment: @jpw since that request is on MSE we can't close this as a dup

Comment: @bluefeet Oh did not know this, thanks. It seems Shog9 solved it for me though.