# Can we stop suggesting both Sql-Server and MySql in the suggested tags?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-tags

So I was posting a question today that was obviously enough about SQL.

At the bottom I saw the little "Suggested Tags" widget trying to be helpful, recommending Sql-Server and MySQL.

And then it hit me.  That's why so many new users tag their SQL questions with both `Sql-Server` and `MySQL`, which I assure you, causes no small measure of frustration among those of us who are experts in one of the two, but not both.   Count how many comments have something like "Which is it?   SQL Server or MySQL?   It can't be both" if you're feeling ambitious/bored.

Can we please stop this?   Maybe just suggest the SQL tag?

I've already seen [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274624/adding-an-you-tagged-this-as-sql-maybe-you-should-also-tag-as-specific-dbms-hi) question, and the duplicate it points to.  I understand the reason why we offer both of these tags, trying to get the poster to focus their question to their specific RDBMS, but it's back-firing and causing them to use a shotgun instead of a laser.   Nice idea, but it didn't work, IMO.   Time to put it to pasture, please?

---

NB: The "Suggested tags" appear to be sent back from the Server in the response to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask (along with other functionality such as draft saving and returning the list of "Questions that may already have your answer")

An example screenshot (of an entirely fictitious question) is below

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, 3.6k questions with both those tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&tags=mysql%20sql-server&mode=all&pageSize=50

Comment: So you have a sense of my pain.  :)

Comment: I think this is a symptom that the help/warning dialog for sql questions doesn't appear if the users choose a DBMS tag but not the general [tag:sql] tag.  But it's probably hard to determine which tags other than sql need that help text.

Comment: The suggested tags come from a separate algorithm entirely different from the popup advising to pick a RDBMS AFAIK. I think the popup is just a reminder not an actual tag picker. So I don't think it is valid to conflate the two things. I'd like to see the popup get smarter not put out to pasture.

Comment: @MartinSmith Smarter, like what?

Comment: I think people just pick MySql if SQL is in anyway involved.  It shows up on a lot of NET OleDB/Access questions too.

Comment: @Plutonix Blame `MySQL` for the name, I think most people pick it because they think `my sql server/database` not realizing that's not what it means.

Comment: @bluefeet Only pop the reminder if a RDBMS isn't selected. And in an ideal world detect likely contradictory tags such as SQL Server and MySql and warn about that too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286965/can-we-get-a-warning-when-a-user-tags-multiple-dbmss

Comment: @bluefeet If anyone is to blame, it is Microsoft for giving their DBMS an overly generic name.  I would suspect that in instances where both tags are used, MySQL is the correct product, not SQL Server.

Comment: @cimmanon, I don't see how its Microsoft's fault that whoever created the sql-server tag didn't add an ms- in front of it.

Comment: @developerwjk Renaming the tag was rejected as being "unproductive" (see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262934/rename-sql-server-tag-to-ms-sql-server)

Comment: @cimmanon If anyone  should be blamed for the overly generic name it should by Sybase and not Microsoft ;)

Comment: I'm seeing a lot more of this lately where MySQL is auto-suggested on SQL Server questions and people with MySQL questions are tagging it as SQL Server because MySQL is a kind *of* SQL server. Having tags flagged as "possibly contradictory" might help. Like Ruby + Python would mean "Are you sure your question relates to both languages?"

Comment: I'm hoping my [request here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357408/can-we-remove-the-mysql-server-tag-synonym) will help with this issue.

Answer (score 11):

Just so we are all on the same page, here's what happens when you type "sql" into the tag text box:

[image: Popup hell]

That's pretty messy. If I were to attempt to make it clearer what's going on, I'd probably remove the [helpful popup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/1438) and not the list of suggested tags. Most of the advice in the warning is unrelated to which tag to pick.

But I'm also not convinced there's a problem with questions getting both tags. Looking through the [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&tags=mysql%20sql-server&mode=all&pageSize=50) (hat tip: [gunr2171](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags#comment241454_304143)), I see a fair number that are comparing features of the two engines:

- [System views in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284418/system-views-in-mysql)
- [Why there are multiple storage motors in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117667/why-there-are-multiple-storage-motors-in-mysql)
- [MySQL "World" database for MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733446/mysql-world-database-for-ms-sql-server)

Or are asking about doing something on two different servers:

- [How to use dbdeploy with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666434/how-to-use-dbdeploy-with-sql-server)
- [queuing multiple SQL queries as one string, server behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714309/queuing-multiple-sql-queries-as-one-string-server-behaviour)
- [Do I have to use OpenQuery to query a MySQL Linked Server from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187234/do-i-have-to-use-openquery-to-query-a-mysql-linked-server-from-sql-server)

These aren't necessarily great questions, but they do seem to be cases where both tags might be appropriate.

It would be a real problem if many of the questions are asking about one engine and including both tags out of confusion or a misunderstanding of tagging. And even then, it's mostly a problem if the answers are totally incompatible.

Finally, as [bluefeet notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags#comment241475_304143) much of the problem stems from terribly generic naming of these products.

Comment: Can you do a search on questions initially tagged with both tags then later had one edited out?

Comment: Also you aren't showing the suggested tags (these appear from parsing the question text and or title before even beginning to type in the tags text box)

Comment: (Suggested tags feature looks like this  http://i.stack.imgur.com/uKxpZ.png)

Comment: @MartinSmith: I understand that OPs misusing tags is a problem and a frustration. But there's only been 2892 time when the OP tagged with both and a later edit removed [tag:sql-server] and 2737 when it was [tag:mysql] that was removed. That sounds bad until you realize that the baseline is 100s of thousands of questions. Also, these are _successful_ outcomes since someone was able to divine which tag applied.

Comment: Thanks. I would have guessed it was more than that.

Comment: When you say the baseline is 100k's, do you mean 100k's of questions that were originally tagged with both sql-server and MySQL?  And if so, what happened to them, since there's apparently now only 3.6k?

Comment: @TabAlleman: Oh no. My point is that the overwhelming number of questions about MySQL or SQL Server were initially tagged with just one or the other. Unfortunately a tiny sliver of a huge number is still quite a few questions. I'm afraid there is probably no solution to this problem except to continue correcting the (thankfully rare) cases when both tags are applied inappropriately.