# Should SO force tagging the database engine for SQL questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Reading [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips), I can see SO added a tooltip to encourege users opening a SQL tagged question to add more relevant SQL driver (engine) tags.

But in reality it seems this tooltip doesn't deliver. It has none or very litter impact - still too many SQL questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175231/sum-column-in-last-row)) are tagged with the SQL tag but without tagging the database engine the OP is referring to (Access, MS-SQL, Oracle etc.). This almost always results in downvoting such questions and with tons of comments asking the OP to specify "Which database are you using?", and in some cases, closing the question as "unclear what you're asking".

I really can't imagine a question general to SQL as a database language only, since this language varies between the different engines.

Should SO force tagging one of the database engines for questions opened only with the SQL tag?

And if I may be even bolder, since it has no real right to exist alone, should the SQL tag be deprecated?

Comment: [We are doing the best we can to motivate people to provide the required information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634). Not a good sign that it is not working.

Comment: @CodyGray Seems this message has no or very little impact - in reality, I dare to say *most* of the SQL questions are opened without a driver tag

Comment: I see the problem, but am not sure if that's the right way to go about it (since SO would need to know all valid database engine tags for SQL). Maybe we should introduce an option to disallow a certain tag to be used alone, and make a more explicit tooltip pop up if it is used alone.  That way, you can also use the functionality for more tags (such as [tag:arrays] or even [tag:regex]) where functionality differs per language

Comment: Presumably, for those few people who actually mean it, we could have `iso-sql`.

Comment: *"Should SO force tagging one of the database engines for questions opened only with the SQL tag?"* - I ask myself, how many people would screw up and mix-match MySQL and SQLServer? [Probably a lot...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags)

Comment: Isn't there a subset of SQL that applies to all, regardless of the actual DBMS? Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: I suspect many of the posters don't know it makes a difference. Some might not even know there are other SQL databases at all (new php developers probably haven't seen anything other than MySQL, and new .net developers probably haven't seen anything other than SQL Server). They would assume that "please specify which engine you're using" doesn't apply to them, reasoning that their problem is with the language, not with a particular backend. Better to educate them, but I doubt that would fit in the tiny info box. Without that, I expect forcing a tag would just make them pick at random.

Comment: And what if a new user or lower rep user is using some esoteric database engine that has no tag? They don't have the reputation to create the tag, but if you disallow them from continuing without selecting an engine tag they'll be forced to intentionally pick an incorrect one.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't know how familiar you are with various SQL dialects, but I can tell you: No. While there is a concept of ANSI SQL, it's often not full-featured enough to cater for common use cases, and many implementations have bugs / quirks which are important enough that users must know how to get around them. That's why all ORMs spend effort detecting which dialect they're connected to. To see how this matters with even the simplest of queries, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/595155/1180785

Comment: @Dave Obviously a "first 10" query isn't the simplest possible query. It's simpler without the restriction. ANSI SQL does exist, and banning it as a question topic (which is effectively what this proposal would do) seems extreme.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley we have an [tag:ansi-sql] tag, that should be one of the allowed database engines. The proposal doesn't ban ANSI SQL at all. You can just use that tag.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley sure, in many cases ANSI is enough. But when somebody's asking a question, they can't know that it will be (if for some reason they *need* a portable ANSI solution, whether it suffices or not is implicitly part of the question, and as Erik says, 'ansi-sql' fills that role). Also I think you misinterpreted "the simplest of queries"; I intended to point out that even queries which seem trivial to newcomers can end up needing dialect-specific answers, rather than "the simplest possible query" (which I guess might be `SELECT 1`?)

Comment: @Dave: SELECT 1 is db-specific. SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1)) X([1]); seems to be the smallest portable version.

Comment: @Joshua wow, the irony of it! :D

Comment: @Joshua Either there's a typo there, or that doesn't work in mysql (5.0)

Comment: @Izkata: mysql doesn't attempt to implement ansi sql at all.

Comment: @Joshua Ah, the way previous comments were phrased, it sounded like ANSI SQL was a limited subset that they did all implement, it was just too limited for general use.  So it sounds like, to Peter's and Dave's comments that started this chain, the answer isn't "almost", it really is "none".

Comment: @Joshua: There are SQL databases for which `SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1)) X([1])` does not work.  I'm not even sure what it is supposed to do (the `X([1])` part of the notation has me bemused), but it doesn't work in Informix (and neither does `SELECT 1`).  If your notation is much more complex than `SELECT * FROM SomeTable`, you are likely to run into issues somewhere along the line.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1)) X([1])` and `SELECT 1` don't work in Oracle either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: To be fair, selecting something without a table is pretty esoteric. I had to go look up the syntax to write it; that's how little it comes up in practice. The X([1]) declares the inline results has table alias named X with a single column named 1.

Comment: @Joshua — Ah; the square brackets are the SQL Server 'delimited identifier' notation.  It makes sense now, but square brackets for delimited identifiers is not portable.  Informix doesn't support the VALUES list in the FROM clause either.  All of which goes to support the notion that the SQL tag without a DBMS tag is seldom useful (not never useful).  It's a problem. It probably requires eternal vigilance by the more knowledgeable denizens of the SQL tag to deal with the issue of the unidentified server type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Oh right; I forgot that different engines use different markers for quoted identifier and tried to mimic the result of select 1 too closely. Easy to fix if you want a column name that looks like an identifier.