# Can we remove the [mysql-server] tag synonym

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonym-process

**Related reading:**

[Can we stop suggesting both Sql-Server and MySql in the suggested tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags)

This part of [Jon's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304147/57475):

> But I'm also not convinced there's a problem with questions getting both tags. Looking through the search results (hat tip: gunr2171), I see a fair number that are comparing features of the two engines:
>
> These aren't necessarily great questions, but they do seem to be cases where both tags might be appropriate.
>
> It would be a real problem if many of the questions are asking about one engine and including both tags out of confusion or a misunderstanding of tagging. And even then, it's mostly a problem if the answers are totally incompatible.

One of the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags/304147#comment241479_304147) from [Martin Smith](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) I believe is in response to the above:

> Can you do a search on questions initially tagged with both tags then later had one edited out?

---

The reason there aren't ***n*** times more posts with both tags is because people that are active in the tags, me included, are constantly requesting that users pick the correct tags when it's clear the post has been tagged incorrectly, as a high percentage of posts don't warrant the use of both tags.

I see this as problem that arises even when you're typing your first tag as [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) as the suggested tags still show you [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), see below:

[image]

So with the first tag added, [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) is the next tag suggested, which I can only assume is due to the synonym [mysql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-server).

Can I request that this synonym is removed, as it simply re-points to [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) and is more than likely the reason that a lot of lower tier questions get tagged with both and it adds little to no value.

Just to complete the circle... it doesn't work both ways:

[image]

**Update**

After seeing [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643220/update-with-select-and-cases-when-then) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638767/how-to-sum-the-values-of-two-rows-in-sql-server) [tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638209/java-jdbc-trouble-deleting-sql-rows-from-online-database) [incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632243/how-to-display-label-based-on-maximum-count-in-database-asp-net-c-sharp) today:

[image]

I decided to get a very rough idea of the amount of times users have commented requesting the tags be fixed, I created a [SEDE Query to check where a comment contains both `*sql-server*` and `*mysql*`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/737054/comments-containing-mysql-sql-server). This returned **3199** results.

This obviously doesn't include:

- Instances where comments were deleted if tags were fixed
- Instances where a user fixed the tags based on syntax of post, so didn't require a comment

Obviously there will be instances where this may have been a legitimate comment or commentary on an answer with both tags, but my feeling is that they would *possibly* be in the minority and be outweighed by the comments that were likely deleted.

Comment: Is [mysql-server] actually a thing? Is there ever a reason why someone might try and use that tag?

Comment: @CodyGray My guess is it is a reference to MySQL & Server, weird yes but it is understandable.

Comment: @CodyGray it's not actually used, it just repoints to [mysql] if you navigate to it. My assumption about it was what bluefeet said. Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-server

Comment: I'm not sure [this data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags/304147#comment241488_304147) is completely accurate. Is this counting questions where both tags remain, some of which would be valid? all versions of the [sql-server*] tag?

Comment: Honestly, I see a lot of questions wrongly tagged MySQL in the [tag:ms-access] tag too. I'm not sure this synonym explains why people tag it wrong (perhaps some people think: hey, my problem could also occur in other database engines, let's tag my question with all of them)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth there's [35k questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) tagged with [ms-access] and [10k questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access%20sql?mode=all) tagged with [ms-access] and [sql], and when you ask a question and add the [sql] tag, [mysql] is suggested, but that's due to the [sql] tag, not this synonym. the [sql] tag is another case altogether.

Comment: @CodyGray just wondered if you had any feedback on this request or what is my best avenue to get this actioned? I was hoping it wouldn't disappear in to the ether.

Comment: I'm certainly not going to do it unilaterally. I have no domain experience here, so can't judge the correctness of the action. I basically still have the same question I asked in the very first comment. What bluefeet says makes sense. What you said just explained what a tag synonym is, which I already understand quite well. There is no real way to get a retag request actioned unless you get a mod who understands the tech and can make an executive decision, or you build up a critical mass of community support. We've a *lot* of pending retag requests. Some inevitably fall through the cracks.