# Is there a way to force users to choose their Bootstrap version for a question?

Tags: support, feature-request

Here's the problem: There are two Bootstrap versions: Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4. They are fundamentally different and NOT compatible with each other.

So, it's absolutely essential for answering a Bootstrap related question to know whether the user is dealing with Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4. About half of the time (or more) users fail to specify their Bootstrap version and use the `twitter-bootstrap` tag.

Result: Instead of answering the question you end up wasting time and posting comments asking the user to specify their Bootstrap version. Very annoying.

One possible solution could be to force the user to pick either one of these two: `bootstrap-3` or `bootstrap-4` (and to retire the `twitter-bootstrap` tag). Is there a way to do that or something similar?

Note: Because those 2 Bootstrap versions are fundamentally different, there is NO case where the user would want to specify both tags (`bootstrap-3` and `bootstrap-4`). It's always either the one OR the other. Never both at the same time.

**UPDATE:**

Twitter itself has dropped the word "Twitter" from "Twitter Bootstrap" when they released Bootstrap 2.0 in January 2012. So, it's actually been 6 years now since Twitter Bootstrap was officially renamed to just Bootstrap. No one who has even remotely a clue refers to Bootstrap as "Twitter Bootstrap". That tag is hopelessly outdated!

**PROPOSAL:**

To solve the problem, the `twitter-bootstrap` tag should now be retired (and prevented from creating anew). A using asking a Bootstrap related question would then be automatically forced to pick either the `bootstrap-3` tag or the `bootstrap-4` tag.

And in the event a user would try to pick both tags, some sort of alert should pop up telling the user to pick only one of those 2 tags because those 2 versions are NOT compatible and it's **essential for answering the question** to know which version is at play.

**IMPORTANT:**

The tag `bootstrap` does not currently exist and the creation of this tag **must be prevented at all cost!** That will prevent any confusion and force people to **choose between the existing tags** which are `bootstrap-3` and `bootstrap-4`.

And in case a user picks both tags (`bootstrap-3` and `bootstrap-4`) they must get an alert popup telling them that choosing both of those tags for the same question is a known cause of deadly cancer! Or something like that. :-)

**Q&A:**

Question from TinyGiant: What if someone is asking about the differences between the two versions?

Answer: In those **extremely rare** cases (and they will always be extremely rare) people can pick any ONE of the two available tags! I can assure you that we (the folks who answer Bootstrap related questions) would NOT mind if we get such a rare question once a month! What we do mind is that we get 100 wrongly classified or unclassified Bootstrap questions a DAY! THAT's the problem!

Comment: These things exist: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304147/578411 not sure if that will fly / can work here.  Or alternatively: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips

Comment: Sounds like [tag:twitter-bootstrap] simply shouldn't exist, and the only tags should be the version specific tags, if they're really that divergent.

Comment: This meta search reveals some lost battles :  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=twitter%20bootstrap

Comment: *Instead of answering the question you end up wasting time and posting comments asking the user to specify their Bootstrap version.* - Not that this would save time but it seems like a legit use of an Unclear flag.

Comment: bootstrap is not distinct enough in the field of software development. Hence the twitter prefix.

Comment: So this is for you bootstrap, the frontend framework made by twitter? [A bootstrap is a series of procedures ran when an application starts up or a request over the web is received.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping)

Comment: I think what Christian is pointing out is that the word bootstrap on its own (there is no capitalisation in tag names) will not be recognised by many as "the thing formerly known as Twitter Bootstrap". I realise that adding version numbers to the tag name **ought** to tip people off, but it is very likely that some people posting a question about bootstrapping will randomly add bootstrap-3 or bootstrap-4 as a tag on their post. It might be worth considering twitter-bootstrap-3 and twitter-bootstrap-4 to avoid confusion.

Comment: boostrapping is not my tag. It is helpful for tag names to be easily and uniquely (to the extent possible, given the character limit) associated with the product or concept they are supposed to apply to. I simply suggest that adding "twitter" to the tag name may avoid confusion (not for people familiar with Twitter's Boostrap product, but for everyone else).

Comment: Re: your last sentence of your most recent edit: What if someone is asking about the differences between the two versions?

Comment: You have allowed your thinking to be walled into a very limited area of programming which is the Bootstrap framework from/by Twitter. You continue to ignore that the word "bootstrap" had a multi-decade long history in programming before the World Wide Web even existed, let alone prior to the existence of the framework you are interested in.

Comment: Ambiguous tags should be avoided. Tag names for projects with generic names are commonly formatted with a prefix to indicate what area of computing they are associated with. [tag:bootstrap-3] and [tag:bootstrap-4] are too ambiguous. They need something which will distinguish them from other uses. The seemingly logical tags are [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3] and [tag:twitter-bootstrap-4], as twitter is what it's most associated with. Another possibility might be "web-". If you don't like those, then propose something else as the prefix, but a prefix is needed.

Answer (score 5):

As [rene pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361996/is-there-a-way-to-force-users-to-choose-their-bootstrap-version-for-a-question#comment548557_361996), we have a [functionality to send warnings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304147/2441442) on a specifc tag.

[image: SQL Warning]

I propose, doing the same for [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).

It should suggest adding [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) or [twitter-bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-4).

As per Update of the question: We could also use it without twitter prefix, but I am not sure, if this would be ambiguous.

We have for example:

- [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) A *bootstrap* is a series of procedures ran when an application starts up or a request over the web is received.
- [statistics-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics-bootstrap) In statistics, a *bootstrap* is a test based on random sampling with replacement.

I have opened a [dedicated question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362057/how-do-we-name-our-bootstrap-version-tags-css-js-framework) for the tag naming.

Comment: The `twitter-` prefix should be removed. So the following tags are available: `bootstrap`, `bootstrap-3` and `bootstrap-4`. People who know about Bootstrap (or the old version Twitter Bootstrap) are using the `bootstrap` tags. Adding a warning to specify the version is good. But I think it is not enough because for the `sql` tag it is not working good enough (there are many new questions tagged as `sql` but missing the DBMS tag). There should be a solution like: You add the `bootstrap` tag and you have to add the version specific tag too. Without this additional tag you can't ask the question.