# How do we name our Bootstrap Version Tags (CSS/JS Framework)?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

**Introduction**

The Feature Request *[Is there a way to force users to choose their Bootstrap version for a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361996/is-there-a-way-to-force-users-to-choose-their-bootstrap-version-for-a-question)*
, introduces a discussion about the tagnames for the CSS/JS Framework Bootstrap.

I feel, that this discussion about tagnames should be seperated from the feature-request, which is requesting a force of a specific version tag. That way we have dedicated answers argumenting why one tag should be prefered to the other. In fact, the tag naming is irrelevant to the feature.

So coming to the point: I am wondering what would be the correct tag for refering to a Bootstrap Version of the CSS Framework.

**Discussion**

For Bootstrap 4 we currently have 2 tags:

[twitter-bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-4) [bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4)

Clearly one does need to be made a synoym of another. For the previous version, we only have [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3)

Do we need a `twitter`-prefix?

**Concerns**

In software development, `bootstrap` can refer to many things. For example, we have the following tags:

- [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) A *bootstrap* is a series of procedures ran when an application starts up or a request over the web is received.
- [statistics-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics-bootstrap) In statistics, a *bootstrap* is a test based on random sampling with replacement.

As a Bootstrap user, I can see Arguments for and against a prefix. What do you - the community - think about?

Which of the both Bootstrap 4 tags is the correct one?

That said, whats about the [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap), which does not contain a specific version?

Comment: Just to note: the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#community) already recommends to use the existing bootstrap-4 tag. Clearly the wish is to completely disassociate it with Twitter (which makes sense IMO). If we're going to keep twitter-bootstrap-4 it should be a synonym of bootstrap-4 IMO.

Comment: @DanielA.White nice find. Except that this is not then really a duplicate but more of a revisit as the linked meta's result was to actually retag 'bootstrap' to twitter-bootstrap; this time it's the twitter-bootstrap tag that is in front of the judge.

Comment: Ironicly the proposed change `bootstrap-framework` is now a synonym of `twitter-bootstrap`

Comment: I stick to what I said in the previous comment, so reopen vote cast...